# Vim ignores window splitting settings in netrw

Tags: vim, netrw

I would prefer if vim opens new windows on the right old window (when using vsplit) and under old window (when using split).
I read that I should `set splitright` and `set splitbelow` to my `.vimrc`. I added also `g:netrw_altv=1` and `g:netrw_alto=1`. This settings doesn't work in netrw browser when I hit `v` button or type `:vsplit file.txt`.

My .vimrc:

```
syntax enable
set splitright
set splitbelow
let g:netrw_altv=1
let g:netrw_alto=1
set background=dar
colorscheme solarized
let g:solarized_termtrans=1
set t_Co=256
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smartindent
set smarttab
set gfn=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 11
set hls
set showmatch
set smartcase
set wildmenu
map <F2> :retab <CR> :wq! <CR>
```

Comment: What does `verbose set splitbelow? splitright?` give you?

Comment: Do you have `+vertsplit` and `+windows` options compiled into your version of vim? `splitright` and `splitbelow` don't work without them

Comment: @FDinoff - it works but not in `netrw`. I tried also add `g:netrw_altv=1` with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a bug in netrw. Updating it solved it.
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075

Answer (score 0):

Strange, as `:vsp` opens a new split on the right, and `:sp` on the bottom even without the options in my machine. You might want to take a look at this thread: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/51334

Comment: I found this thread earlier.
About using `splitright` and `splitbelow` I read here: [link](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vim-annoyances/).